# Create Multiple Posts with close to 2000 images from ftp directory

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have close to 2000 "paint color" images and the same amount of "paint color" Images with a brush over the color. I ultimately want to create a filterable gallery to display all of the colors and would filter depending on the color. The color hover state would be the brush over the color version.

So I would like to know if anyone has any ideas for an easier way to possibly upload these images in bulk in WordPress as well as create posts with all of these images. At first I was going to upload all images into a folder via ftp and use a woocommerce csv linking to the images and uploading the csv to woocommerce to create product posts in bulk.

But I was wondering if there is an easier way to simply create a custom post type and point to the ftp directory of the images and bulk create posts in that custom post type with the image either as a featured image or as an image field in advanced custom fields.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Or is woocommerce the easiest option for now as I can do it manually but it would take a very long time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `wp.Uploader` javascript event to get uploaded attachment response data.

Using this javascript below, if page is `/wp-admin/upload.php`, and when the each attachment finishes processing, this will fire an an ajax request to create woocommerce products.

```js
// document ready
(function($) {

    // if pagenow is upload
    if(pagenow === 'upload') {

        // extend uploader lister
        $.extend(wp.Uploader.prototype, {
            success: function (attachment) {
                
                // console our attachment attributes data
                console.log(attachment.attributes);

                // jquery ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 300000, // 5 hours
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        action: 'media_upload_generate_product',
                        author_id: attachment.attributes.author,
                        attachment_id: attachment.attributes.id,
                        filename: attachment.attributes.filename,
                        title: attachment.attributes.title,
                        type: attachment.attributes.type
                    },
                    success: function (response) {

                        // log our response
                        console.log(response);
                        
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                        // log our response
                        console.log(response.data.message);

                    }

                }).done(function (response) {

                    // log our response
                    console.log(response);

                });

            }
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

You will need to enqueue the above javascript by adding this to your `functions.php`, you just need to make sure your directory urls point to the right js file location...

```php
// enqueue js and css dist
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js_css', 5);

// enqueue js and css dist
function enqueue_js_css() {

    // re-register jquery
    $filename = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/admin.js';
    $filepath = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dist/js/admin.js';
    wp_register_script('admin',$filename,[],filemtime($filepath),true);

    // enqueue jquery
    wp_enqueue_script('admin');

}
```

We don't want this to work for every image you upload to the media library. We only want this to run for your paint images. So we use some PHP to filter and run the correct actions via our ajax call above.

So you have two types of image, one is `Paint Color` and the other is `Paint Brush`

If you make sure all `Paint Color` images start with `paintcolor_`, and all spaces are replace with a underscore `_`, for example...

1. `paintcolor_maximum_yellow_red.png`
2. `paintcolor_quinacridone_magenta.png`
3. `paintcolor_quinacridone_magenta.png`
4. `paintcolor_ruby.png`
5. `paintcolor_sky_blue_crayola.png`
6. `paintcolor_teal.png`

Then the same for `Paint Brush` images, make sure they start with start with `paintcolor_` etc...

1. `paintbrush_maximum_yellow_red.png`
2. `paintbrush_quinacridone_magenta.png`
3. `paintbrush_quinacridone_magenta.png`
4. `paintbrush_ruby.png`
5. `paintbrush_sky_blue_crayola.png`
6. `paintbrush_teal.png`

You want to attach two images to one woocommerce product. Which means you need two image custom fields or a single gallery custom field. My example code below shows using two ACF image fields...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxCXk.png

Right so here is the PHP to handle the uploaded attachment, if you read my comments in the code it is really straight forward. This needs to go in your `functions.php` too.

```php
// media upload generate product ajax actions
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_media_upload_generate_product', 'ajax_media_upload_generate_product', 20);
add_action('wp_ajax_media_upload_generate_product', 'ajax_media_upload_generate_product', 20);

// media upload generate product ajax function
function ajax_media_upload_generate_product() {

    // get our passed variables
    $author_id      = (int)$_GET['author_id'];
    $attachment_id  = (int)$_GET['attachment_id'];
    $filename       = (string)$_GET['filename'];
    $title          = (string)$_GET['title'];
    $type           = (string)$_GET['type'];

    // check if file title starts with paintcolor_
    // so we will only run and process images and convert to products if file name starts with paintcolor_
    if(substr($title, 0, 11) === 'paintcolor_') {

        // create our paint color product title
        // strip paintcolor_ from string
        $title = str_replace('paintcolor_', '', $title);

        // explode underscores for paint color titles then implode title parts with a space seperator and then uppercase each word
        $title = ucwords(implode(' ', explode('_', $title)));

        // chech to see if paint colour product already exists
        $paint_color = get_page_by_path(sanitize_title($title), OBJECT, 'product');

        // if paint color is not an object, therefore paint colour has not already been created
        if(!is_object($paint_color)) {

            // set our new product using WC_Product_Simple
            $product = new WC_Product_Simple();

            // build our new woocommerce product using the uploaded attachment data
            $product->set_name($title);
            $product->set_status('publish');
            $product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
            $product->set_price(19.99);
            $product->set_regular_price(19.99);
            $product->set_sold_individually(true);
            $product->set_image_id($attachment_id);
            $product->set_downloadable(true);
            $product->set_virtual(true);

            // store current attachment data
            $src_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full');
            $file_url = reset($src_img);
            $file_md5 = md5($file_url);

            // start new product download using WC_Product_Download
            $download = new WC_Product_Download();
            $download->set_name('Paint Color ' . $title);
            $download->set_id($file_md5);
            $download->set_file($file_url);

            // add new WC_Product_Download to downloads array
            $downloads[$file_md5] = $download;

            // finishing setting downloads and finally save product
            $product->set_downloads($downloads);
            $product->save();

            // add paint color image to paint color acf image field
            update_field('paint_color',$attachment_id,$product->get_id());

            // send json success response
            wp_send_json_success((array)$product);

        } else {

            // force delete duplicate media item
            wp_delete_post($attachment_id,true);

            // send json error response
            wp_send_json_error(['message' => 'Paint color ' + $title + ' product already exist! Attachment has been deleted.']);

        }

    // check if file title starts with paintbrush_
    // so we will only run and process images if file name starts with paintbrush_
    } elseif(substr($title, 0, 11) === 'paintbrush_') {

        // create our paint color product title
        // strip paintbrush_ from string
        $title = str_replace('paintbrush_', '', $title);

        // explode underscores for paint color titles then implode title parts with a space seperator and then uppercase each word
        $title = ucwords(implode(' ', explode('_', $title)));

        // chech to see if paint color already exists
        $paint_color = get_page_by_path(sanitize_title($title), OBJECT, 'product');

        // if paint color is an object, therefore paint color has already been created
        // and paint color object has property ID
        if(is_object($paint_color) && property_exists($paint_color,'ID')) {

            // get our existing product using WC_Product_Simple
            $product = new WC_Product_Simple($paint_color->ID);

            // store current attachment data
            $src_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full');
            $file_url = reset($src_img);
            $file_md5 = md5($file_url);

            // get current downloads
            $downloads = $product->get_downloads('edit');

            // start new product download using WC_Product_Download
            $download = new WC_Product_Download();
            $download->set_name('Paint Brush ' . $title);
            $download->set_id($file_md5);
            $download->set_file($file_url);

            // add new WC_Product_Download to downloads array
            $downloads[$file_md5] = $download;

            // finishing setting downloads and finally save product
            $product->set_downloads($downloads);
            $product->save();

            // add paint brush image to paint brush acf image field
            update_field('paint_brush',$attachment_id,$paint_color->ID);

        } else {

            // force delete duplicate media item
            wp_delete_post($attachment_id,true);

            // send json error response
            wp_send_json_error(['message' => 'Paint brush color ' + $title + ' product does not exist yet so cannot add attachment to ACF paint brush field. This attachment has been deleted.']);

        }

    } else {

        // send json error response
        wp_send_json_error(['message' => 'Cannot generate product because filename does not start with `paintcolor_`']);

    }

    // death becomes us
    die();

}
```

Obviously you will need to tweek how you handle pricing and other woocommerce product data. I've put some options in the `$product` and included downloads too.

I've tested this and it works.

It also handles duplicates, and deletes the attachment if attachment already exists with the same name.

You must upload all your `paintcolor_` images first, in order for the `paintbrush_` images to have a wooproduct to attach too.

Images I used to test... https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLy9X.jpg